# Who was it in the black and white photo on The Doctor's desk?

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification

In Episode 1 of Series 10, *"The Pilot"*, the Doctor has 2 photos on his desk in the university: one large colour photo of River Song and a smaller one in black and white.

[image: Black and White Photo next to River Song]

So who was it in the black and white photo on the Doctor's desk?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### [Susan Foreman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Foreman), granddaughter and very first Companion to the Doctor.

The photograph seen in "The Pilot" appears to be a cropped and re-backgrounded version of [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Susan_Foreman.jpg), which according to Wikipedia is a copyrighted BBC "publicity still":

[image: Full image]
[image: Cropped]
[image: For comparison]

The first episode of Series 10 has long been marketed as a "brand new start", an episode like "Rose" or "The Eleventh Hour" where someone new to *Doctor Who* could start watching and understand everything without needing extra context or background. So it makes sense to include callbacks to "An Unearthly Child", the first episode *ever*, and by extension to the first Companion *ever*, whose Companionhood even predates the show itself.

Also, the new Doctor-Companion relationship, from what we've seen of it so far, feels much more like Old Who than New. Instead of a handsome, young-looking man who gets women falling for him left and right, we have an old, wise, slightly grumpy man who takes a much younger woman under his wing as a pupil. It's early days yet, of course, but right now the Capaldi-Bill dynamic feels much more like Hartnell-Susan than, say, Tennant-Rose or Smith-Clara.

Comment: Plus that he has a male companion as well. That too was much more common in old Who.

Comment: @MrLister I suspect there may be more to Nardole than meets the eye, and he's not just another Companion ...

Comment: On that topic, I do hope Matt Lucas stays with the show, at least until the end of Capaldi's run. He is the perfect comic relief (Ooh, bante!. Your turn), and foil.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Ugh, I never liked the character of Nardole. But I remain open to being convinced as this series progresses.

Answer (score 27):

Although correctly identified as Susan Foreman, from the very first ever Doctor Who, the two photos together are very significant.

It shows the Doctor with photos of his *family* on his desk. Not just companions.

Comment: Ooh, I'll have to watch it again now and look for a photo of Jenny.

Comment: @MrLister - I'm not sure The Doctor considers Jenny to be family. He was not very accepting of her (and tbh, I don't recall if that was ever resolved in the episode).

Comment: @amflare Not very accepting of her? Don't you remember [how it ended](https://youtu.be/0cuXrLw_Fss?t=1m3s)?

Comment: @MrLister - Ahhh. You are correct. I had forgotten that ending and only remembered the parts where he was trying to avoid the whole issue.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to assume that in all the excitement he never had any chance to take photographs of Jenny. I don't remember the story very well (haven't watched it since it first aired) but I can't imagine there'd be any chance to go back and get pictures!

Answer (score 9):

That is Susan Foreman, the Doctor's first companion and granddaughter. BBC America has [more information on her](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2011/09/a-companion-to-the-doctors-companions-susan-foreman), including what appears to be this very photo.